# Can I query “medLast10QueryTime” on the web in the single mode?

Tags: performance, dolphindb

In the [tutorial](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/SystemManagement/PerformanceMonitoring.html), I saw that the following monitoring indicators can be queried from the web, such as:
“medLast10QueryTime”: The median time it takes to complete the first 10 queries
“maxLast10QueryTime”: The maximum time it takes to complete the first 10 queries
I can't find these indicators on the web in the single mode. How should I check them?

Answer (score 0):

For standalone mode, the indicators displayed on the web have been simplified due to typographical reasons. Currently, the corresponding indicator values ​​can be obtained by executing the following script:

```py
select maxLast10QueryTime, maxLast10QueryTime from getClusterPerf()
```